# How to efficiently update css on multiple selector classes in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, widget, themes

I want to update the css of a lot of classes of objects with the same value. For example:

```
$("selector1").css("background-color", "#abc");
$("selector2").css("background-color", "#abc");
...
$("selector50").css("background-color", "#abc");
```

I'm using a widget framework with literally hundreds of classes whose css I need to update with a handful of jquery functions, kind of like a simplified themeroller visualisation. At the moment I'm going through my css file and adding the classes to a javascript array in my code, and then the user can update the css via an automatically-triggered `arrayOfSelectors.each()` function when they update the `<input type="color">`, for example.

It's pretty manually intensive to assemble all the widget classes into an array. Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Put a class on all the `#selectorX` elements and use one selector to grab them all. You should also really put the style within a CSS class and use `addClass` instead of `css()`

Comment: Use class instead of using inline styles. And also use class on all the common elements on which the styles need to be updated. Or use DOM hierarchy, if possible.

Comment: @Rory, you mean `arrayOfSelectors.each(addClass("customCSS"))` and update `$(".customCSS").css()` when the user changes the theme inputs?

Comment: You mean add `class="customCSS"` class to each relevant tag in the html, and then `$(".customCSS").css()`? The css still needs to be updated dynamically; I don't see how I can avoid calling .css() inline?

Comment: @Escher Right. For dynamic properties you've to use `.css`. But for static properties use class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a common class for all the elements. note that elements can have multiple classes. then you can use like,

```
$(".commonClass").css("background-color", "#abc");
```

Or you can use comma separated selectors like this as well,

```
$("selector1,selector2,selector3").css("background-color", "#abc");
```

The other option is to use attribute starts with selector.

```
$("[id^=selector]").css("background-color", "#abc");
```

this will select all the elements, whose id is starts with "selector".

Comment: `commonClass` it is then.

Answer (score 0):

using comma separated multiple selector. Like this:

```
$("selector1,selector2").css("background-color", "#abc")
```